# FFTW In Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, fftw

Is possible to use FFTW on Android NDK?. I've been searching a lot and there are info about this topic, but I cannot make FFTW work on my project. I found this problems while I were looking for info:

- Most of posts I've found have instructions for Eclipse, but I'm using Android Studio in my project and migrating it to Eclipse is not an option now.
- I don't have an Android.mk file in my project, I think this file was removed in recent versions of Android NDK. I only have CMakeLists.txt to configure and include libraries.

Due to this facts, I cannot understand most of the explanations I've found. In addition to that, I'm pretty new with Andorid NDK (only worked with it a couple of times) and I've never used an external library in NDK before.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me the procedure to include FFTW in my Android Studio project so I can use it from Android NDK.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes I was able to use the FFTW library with Android NDK using this tool: https://github.com/Lauszus/fftw3-android

You have to build the library locally on your computer using the build script.

You can use the Android.mk file in the README, just make modifications to it so that it points on the built library.

You also need an Application.mk file, like in this tutorial: http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/androidndk1

You will need to configure Gradle via the Android Studio UI to set up your project as a NDK project: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds

After this you should be able to create a .cpp file and try including the header

```
#include <fftw3.h>
```

and hopefully your project should compile.

I suggest installing the FFTW library to your local development computer and writing some toy FFTW code locally before porting that to NDK.